# Format a vector of rows in italic and red font in R DT (datatable)

Tags: r, shiny, datatables, dt

A bit similar to this question: [How to give color to a given interval of rows of a DT table?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45542144/how-to-give-color-to-a-given-interval-of-rows-of-a-dt-table)

but in my case I would like to let the user select rows in the table, then on click of a button deselect the rows, and turn the previously selected rows that are now part of the list of rows submitted for removal grayed out font (color: light gray) and in italic. This to indicate that these will be excluded from further analysis. 
Secondly a button to undo the entire selection should change all rows back to normal format

I've gotten as far as recording the selected rows and adding the deselect feature, but to then restyle the rows before resetting them escapes me....

Output that I hope to achieve: 
[image]

Not sure whether it is the right approach, but my thought was to use both 
`values$selected_rows` and `values$removed_rows`, where the first holds the selection until it is submitted, and removed holds the potentially growing list of rows selected for removal if the user decides to remove more rows on another submit

`removed_rows` is then also the list of rows that need to be styled (grayed out in italic)

```
library(shiny)
library(DT)


ui <- fluidPage(
    actionButton('SubmitRemoval', 'Exclude selected rows'),
    actionButton('UndoRemoval', 'Include full data'),
  verbatimTextOutput('Printresult'),
    DT::dataTableOutput('mytable')

)

server <- function(input, output,session) {

  values <- reactiveValues()

  observe({
    values$selected_rows <- input$mytable_rows_selected
  })


  observeEvent(input$SubmitRemoval, { 
        values$removed_rows <- c(values$removed_rows,input$mytable_rows_selected)


    dataTableProxy('mytable') %>% selectRows(NULL)
    values$selected_rows <- NULL
    removeTab("tabs", "mytable")
    })

  Remaining_mtcars <- reactive({ 
    req( values$removed_rows)
    mtcarsR <- mtcars[-c(values$removed_rows), ]
    mtcarsR
    })

  output$Printresult <- renderText({ nrow(Remaining_mtcars()) })

  observeEvent(input$UndoRemoval, {
    values$removed_rows <- NULL

    })

  output$mytable <- DT::renderDataTable({
    DT::datatable(mtcars,  
                  extensions = c('Buttons', 'ColReorder', 'FixedHeader', 'Scroller'),
                  options = list(pageLength = 25,
                                 selection = c('multiple'),
                                 dom = 'frtipB'
    )
  )
  })
}
runApp(list(ui = ui, server = server))
```

**UPDATE**
@SL: I tried to move your javascript functions for submit and undo inside the DT::JS() part of embedded buttons, but I could not get it to work. I guess i'm close, but no idea where the problem is.

The table output code would follow this structure:

```
 output[["mytable"]] <- renderDT({
    datatable(dat, 
              escape = -2, 
              extensions = c('Buttons', 'ColReorder', 'FixedHeader', 'Scroller'),
              callback = JS(callback),
              options = list(
                dom = 'frtipB',
                initComplete = JS(initComplete),
                rowId = JS(sprintf("function(data){return data[%d];}", ncol(dat))), 
                columnDefs = list(
                  list(visible = FALSE, targets = ncol(dat)),
                  list(className = "dt-center", targets = "_all")
                ),
                buttons = list('copy', 'csv',
                               list(
                                 extend = "collection",
                                 text = 'Deselect', 
                                 action = DT::JS("function ( e, dt, node, config ) {
                                       Shiny.setInputValue('SubmitRemoval', true, {priority: 'event'});
                                     }")
                                   ## move the submit javascript here
                                ),
                               list(
                                 extend = "collection",
                                 text = 'Restore', 
                                 action = DT::JS("function ( e, dt, node, config ) {
                                       Shiny.setInputValue('UndoRemoval', true, {priority: 'event'});
 ## move the undo removal javascript here
                                     }")
                               )
                )
              )
    )
  })
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a better solution (it took me several hours). This one does not redraw the table when one clicks the button, and it doesn't go wrong when one sorts the table by a column.

```
library(shiny)
library(DT)

initComplete <- c(
  "function(settings) {",
  "  var table=settings.oInstance.api();", 
  "  $('#SubmitRemoval').on('click', function(){",
  "    table.$('tr.selected').addClass('x');",
  "  });",
  "  $('#UndoRemoval').on('click', function(){",
  "    table.$('tr').removeClass('x');",
  "  });",
  "}"
)

callback <- "
var xrows = [];
table.on('preDraw', function(e, settings) {
  var tbl = settings.oInstance.api();
  var nrows = tbl.rows().count();
  var rows = tbl.$('tr');
  var some = false; var r = 0;
  while(!some && r<nrows){
    if($(rows[r]).hasClass('x')){
      some = true
    }
    r++;
  }
  if(some){
    xrows = [];
    for(var i = 0; i < nrows; i++){
      if($(rows[i]).hasClass('x')){
        xrows.push(rows[i].getAttribute('id'));
      }
    }
  }
}).on('draw.dt', function(){
  for(var i=0; i<xrows.length; i++){
    var row = $('#' + xrows[i]);
    row.addClass('x');
  }
  xrows = [];
});
"

ui <- fluidPage(
  tags$head(
    tags$style(HTML(
      ".x { background-color: rgb(211,211,211) !important; font-style: italic}
       table.dataTable tr.selected.x td { background-color: rgb(211,211,211) !important;}"
    ))
  ),
  actionButton('SubmitRemoval', 'Exclude selected rows'),
  actionButton('UndoRemoval', 'Include full data'),
  br(),
  DTOutput('mytable')

)

server <- function(input, output,session) {

  dat <- cbind(mtcars[1:6,], id=1:6)

  output[["mytable"]] <- renderDT({
    datatable(dat, 
              callback = JS(callback),
              options = list(
                initComplete = JS(initComplete),
                rowId = JS(sprintf("function(a){return a[%d];}", ncol(dat))), 
                columnDefs = list(list(visible=FALSE, targets=ncol(dat)))
              )
    )
  })

  proxy <- dataTableProxy("mytable")

  observeEvent(input[["UndoRemoval"]], { 
    proxy %>% selectRows(NULL)
  })

}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

[image]

## Update

Here is the version including icons:

```
library(shiny)
library(DT)

initComplete <- c(
  "function(settings) {",
  "  var table = settings.oInstance.api();", 
  "  var cross = '<span style=\"color:red; font-size:18px\"><i class=\"glyphicon glyphicon-remove\"></i></span>'",
  "  var checkmark = '<span style=\"color:red; font-size:18px\"><i class=\"glyphicon glyphicon-ok\"></i></span>'",
  "  $('#SubmitRemoval').on('click', function(){",
  "    table.$('tr.selected').addClass('x');",
  "    table.$('tr.selected')",
  "      .each(function(){$(this).find('td').eq(1).html(cross);});",
  "  });",
  "  $('#UndoRemoval').on('click', function(){",
  "    table.$('tr').removeClass('x');",
  "    table.$('tr')",
  "      .each(function(i){$(this).find('td').eq(1).html(checkmark);});",
  "  });",
  "}"
)

callback <- "
var cross = '<span style=\"color:red; font-size:18px\"><i class=\"glyphicon glyphicon-remove\"></i></span>'
var xrows = [];
table.on('preDraw', function(e, settings) {
  var tbl = settings.oInstance.api();
  var nrows = tbl.rows().count();
  var rows = tbl.$('tr');
  var some = false; var r = 0;
  while(!some && r<nrows){
    if($(rows[r]).hasClass('x')){
      some = true
    }
    r++;
  }
  if(some){
    xrows = [];
    for(var i = 0; i < nrows; i++){
      if($(rows[i]).hasClass('x')){
        xrows.push(rows[i].getAttribute('id'));
      }
    }
  }
}).on('draw.dt', function(){
  for(var i=0; i<xrows.length; i++){
    var row = $('#' + xrows[i]);
    row.addClass('x').find('td').eq(1).html(cross);
  }
  xrows = [];
});
"

ui <- fluidPage(
  tags$head(
    tags$style(HTML(
      ".x { background-color: rgb(211,211,211) !important; font-style: italic}
       table.dataTable tr.selected.x td { background-color: rgb(211,211,211) !important;}"
    ))
  ),
  actionButton('SubmitRemoval', 'Exclude selected rows'),
  actionButton('UndoRemoval', 'Include full data'),
  br(),
  DTOutput('mytable')

)

server <- function(input, output,session) {

  dat <- cbind(Selected = '<span style="color:red; font-size:18px"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok"></i></span>', 
               mtcars[1:6,], id = 1:6)

  output[["mytable"]] <- renderDT({
    datatable(dat, 
              escape = -2, 
              callback = JS(callback),
              options = list(
                initComplete = JS(initComplete),
                rowId = JS(sprintf("function(data){return data[%d];}", ncol(dat))), 
                columnDefs = list(
                  list(visible = FALSE, targets = ncol(dat)),
                  list(className = "dt-center", targets = "_all")
                )
              )
    )
  })

  proxy <- dataTableProxy("mytable")

  observeEvent(input[["UndoRemoval"]], { 
    proxy %>% selectRows(NULL)
  })

}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

[image]

## Update

To get the indices of the excluded rows in `input$excludedRows`:

```
initComplete <- c(
  "function(settings) {",
  "  var table = settings.oInstance.api();", 
  "  var cross = '<span style=\"color:red; font-size:18px\"><i class=\"glyphicon glyphicon-remove\"></i></span>'",
  "  var checkmark = '<span style=\"color:red; font-size:18px\"><i class=\"glyphicon glyphicon-ok\"></i></span>'",
  "  $('#SubmitRemoval').on('click', function(){",
  "    table.$('tr.selected').addClass('x');",
  "    table.$('tr.selected')",
  "      .each(function(){$(this).find('td').eq(1).html(cross);});",
  "    var excludedRows = [];",
  "    table.$('tr').each(function(i, row){",
  "      if($(this).hasClass('x')){excludedRows.push(parseInt($(row).attr('id')));}",
  "    });",
  "    Shiny.setInputValue('excludedRows', excludedRows);",
  "  });",
  "  $('#UndoRemoval').on('click', function(){",
  "    table.$('tr').removeClass('x');",
  "    table.$('tr')",
  "      .each(function(i){$(this).find('td').eq(1).html(checkmark);});",
  "    Shiny.setInputValue('excludedRows', null);",
  "  });",
  "}"
)
```

## Update

This is easier with the option `server = FALSE` of `renderDT`:

```
library(shiny)
library(DT)

initComplete <- c(
  "function(settings) {",
  "  var table = settings.oInstance.api();", 
  "  $('#SubmitRemoval').on('click', function(){",
  "    table.$('tr.selected').addClass('x').each(function(){",
  "      var td = $(this).find('td').eq(1)[0];", 
  "      var cell = table.cell(td);", 
  "      cell.data('remove');",
  "    });",
  "    table.draw(false);",
  "    table.rows().deselect();",
  "    var excludedRows = [];",
  "    table.$('tr').each(function(i, row){",
  "      if($(this).hasClass('x')){excludedRows.push(parseInt($(row).attr('id')));}",
  "    });",
  "    Shiny.setInputValue('excludedRows', excludedRows);",
  "  });",
  "  $('#UndoRemoval').on('click', function(){",
  "    table.$('tr').removeClass('x').each(function(){",
  "      var td = $(this).find('td').eq(1)[0];", 
  "      var cell = table.cell(td);", 
  "      cell.data('ok');",
  "    });",
  "    Shiny.setInputValue('excludedRows', null);",
  "  });",
  "}"
)

render <- c(
  'function(data, type, row, meta){',
  '  if(type === "display"){',
  '    return "<span style=\\\"color:red; font-size:18px\\\"><i class=\\\"glyphicon glyphicon-" + data + "\\\"></i></span>";',
  '  } else {',
  '    return data;',
  '  }',
  '}'
)

ui <- fluidPage(
  tags$head(
    tags$style(HTML(
      ".x { color: rgb(211,211,211); font-style: italic; }"
    ))
  ),
  verbatimTextOutput("excludedRows"),
  actionButton('SubmitRemoval', 'Exclude selected rows'),
  actionButton('UndoRemoval', 'Include full data'),
  br(),
  DTOutput('mytable')
)

server <- function(input, output,session) {

  dat <- cbind(Selected = "ok", mtcars[1:6,], id = 1:6)

  output[["mytable"]] <- renderDT({
    datatable(dat, 
              extensions = "Select",
              options = list(
                initComplete = JS(initComplete),
                rowId = JS(sprintf("function(data){return data[%d];}", ncol(dat))), 
                columnDefs = list(
                  list(visible = FALSE, targets = ncol(dat)),
                  list(className = "dt-center", targets = "_all"),
                  list(
                    targets = 1,
                    render = JS(render)
                  ) 
                )
              )
    )
  }, server = FALSE)

  proxy <- dataTableProxy("mytable")

  observeEvent(input[["UndoRemoval"]], { 
    proxy %>% selectRows(NULL)
  })

  output$excludedRows <- renderPrint({
    input[["excludedRows"]]
  })

}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: stephane I am impressed! also where you find the time for all of this. You may have missed it but i posted a new question which now has a bounty on it, which I will gladly award you. The only thing I still would need to add to this then is the conditional icons (see the other question). If you could have a look at it and post this answer on the other question, I can award you the points. 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56099758/how-to-avoid-mixup-between-rowcallback-and-sorting-in-datatable

Comment: Some explanation how this new solution works would be welcome too so that I sort of understand what it does (And how do you figure this out?)

Comment: @Mark I figured this out by working hard, and because I am a JavaScript lover ;-) I will try to give some explanations tomorrow. See my update for the icons. That said, there's still something to do: to get the excluded rows in the server.

Comment: The embedded submit and undo removal plus the observers in my other post might solve that issue.  Have a look on the link I posted in the comment

Comment: @Mark I don't know yet. I've found a solution. See my update.

Comment: Stefane, did you have any luck with the embedded buttons I referred to?

Comment: @Mark I didn't see. Have you tried to replace `table.$('tr.selected').addClass('x')` with `dt.$('tr.selected').addClass('x')` ? I don't know whether this is the solution.

Comment: I posted a test app to a new question here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56306381/move-javascript-functionality-of-buttons-to-embedded-buttons-with-dt-datatable

not sure how replacing table with dt would make a difference? I suppose you would need to replace all table. cases in he script then, but your var is assigned to table =. Changing to dt seems as just a change of names?

Comment: @Mark The button action function has the argument `dt`. This is the same, I think, as `table` in my code. So move my code to the button action function and replace `table` with `dt`. Or simply replace `function(e,dt,node,config)` with `function(e,table,node,config)` and copy my code verbatim (don't forget to include `cross` and `checkmark`).

Comment: @Mark See my latest update. It solves all the issues you mentioned. I failed during a couple of hours, until I tried the option `server = FALSE`. This option is not recommended for large tables, but it really makes things easier. I have added the extension `Select` which allows to deselect the rows.

Comment: cool! not sure if you deliberately went back to the old question, but I will try to copy this to the version with the embedded buttons again. just adding select and server is false there caused some strange side effects on a table with multiple pages, giving the wrong rows, and removing rows on other pages randomly, but this version here works fine it seems

Comment: I think I'm going to need your help to update my script in the other embedded approach Stefan, keep getting weird behaviour and not sure how to implement the changes. I see you added a whole new approach with render function here

Answer (score 1):

Here is an attempt.

```
library(shiny)
library(DT)

rowCallback <- function(rows){
  c(
    "function(row, data, num, index){",
    sprintf("  var rows = [%s];", paste0(rows-1, collapse = ",")),
    "  if(rows.indexOf(index) > -1){",
    "    for(var i=1; i<data.length; i++){",
    "      $('td:eq('+i+')', row)",
    "        .css({'background-color': 'rgb(211,211,211)', 'font-style': 'italic'});",
    "    }",
    "  }",
    "}"  
  )
}

ui <- fluidPage(
  actionButton('SubmitRemoval', 'Exclude selected rows'),
  actionButton('UndoRemoval', 'Include full data'),
  br(),
  DTOutput('mytable')

)

server <- function(input, output,session) {

  output[["mytable"]] <- renderDT({
    input[["SubmitRemoval"]]
    input[["UndoRemoval"]]
    rows <- isolate(input[["mytable_rows_selected"]])
    datatable(mtcars, 
              options = list(
                rowCallback = JS(rowCallback(rows))
              )
    )
  })

  proxy <- dataTableProxy("mytable")

  observeEvent(input[["UndoRemoval"]], { 
    proxy %>% selectRows(NULL)
  })

}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

[image]

Comment: having a look at it now at last. Trying to run it without rownames, and still still apply it to the first column ...

Comment: rowCallback <- function(rows){
  c(
    "function(row, data, num, index){",
    sprintf("  var rows = [%s];", paste0(rows-1, collapse = ",")),
    "  if(rows.indexOf(index) > -1){",
    "    for(var i=0; i<data.length; i++){",
    "      $('td:eq('+i+')', row)",
    "        .css({'color': 'rgb(211,211,211)', 'font-style': 'italic'});",
    "    }",
    "  }",
    "}"  
  )
}
to apply to all columns without rownames

Comment: Stephane, I found out that this goes wrong when the user then sorts the table by a column.

Comment: @Mark Does it work if you replace `rows.indexOf(index)` with `rows.indexOf(num)` ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56099758/how-to-avoid-mixup-between-rowcallback-and-sorting-in-datatable

Answer (score 1):

Here is a variant. Instead of using a button to mark the selected rows as removed, the user clicks on the icons.

```
library(shiny)
library(DT)

callback <- c(
  "table.on('click', 'td:nth-child(2)', function(){",
  "  var td = this;",
  "  var cell = table.cell(td);",
  "  if(cell.data() === 'ok'){",
  "    cell.data('remove');",
  "  } else {",
  "    cell.data('ok');",
  "  }",
  "  var $row = $(td).closest('tr');",
  "  $row.toggleClass('excluded');",
  "  var excludedRows = [];",
  "  table.$('tr').each(function(i, row){",
  "    if($(this).hasClass('excluded')){",
  "      excludedRows.push(parseInt($(row).attr('id')));",
  "    }",
  "  });",
  "  Shiny.setInputValue('excludedRows', excludedRows);",
  "})"
)

restore <- c(
  "function(e, table, node, config) {",
  "  table.$('tr').removeClass('excluded').each(function(){",
  "    var td = $(this).find('td').eq(1)[0];", 
  "    var cell = table.cell(td);", 
  "    cell.data('ok');",
  "  });",
  "  Shiny.setInputValue('excludedRows', null);",
  "}"
)

render <- c(
  'function(data, type, row, meta){',
  '  if(type === "display"){',
  '    return "<span style=\\\"color:red; font-size:18px\\\"><i class=\\\"glyphicon glyphicon-" + data + "\\\"></i></span>";',
  '  } else {',
  '    return data;',
  '  }',
  '}'
)

ui <- fluidPage(
  tags$head(
    tags$style(HTML(
      ".excluded { color: rgb(211,211,211); font-style: italic; }"
    ))
  ),
  fluidRow(
    column(
      6, 
      tags$label("Excluded rows"),
      verbatimTextOutput("excludedRows")
    ),
    column(
      6, 
      tags$label("Included rows"),
      verbatimTextOutput("includedRows")
    )
  ),
  br(),
  DTOutput('mytable')
)

server <- function(input, output,session) {

  dat <- cbind(Selected = "ok", mtcars[1:6,], id = 1:6)

  output[["mytable"]] <- renderDT({
    datatable(dat, 
              extensions = c("Select", "Buttons"), 
              selection = "none", 
              callback = JS(callback),
              options = list(
                rowId = JS(sprintf("function(data){return data[%d];}", ncol(dat))), 
                columnDefs = list(
                  list(visible = FALSE, targets = ncol(dat)),
                  list(className = "dt-center", targets = "_all"),
                  list(className = "notselectable", targets = 1),
                  list(targets = 1, render = JS(render)) 
                ),
                dom = "Bt",
                buttons = list("copy", "csv",
                               list(
                                 extend = "collection",
                                 text = 'Select all rows', 
                                 action = JS(restore)
                               )
                ),
                select = list(style = "single", selector = "td:not(.notselectable)")
              )
    )
  }, server = FALSE)

    output$excludedRows <- renderPrint({
      input[["excludedRows"]]
    })

    output$includedRows <- renderPrint({
      setdiff(1:nrow(dat), input[["excludedRows"]])
    })

}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

[image]

Comment: Just started looking at this. Lets see if I can make it work with a plot linked to it as well. Might be worth posting a separate question on this as this is a nice approach but is a bit lost here now as 3rd answer