# How to avoid mixup between rowcallback and sorting in datatable

Tags: r, datatable, shiny, dt

With the help of a previous [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55550126/format-a-vector-of-rows-in-italic-and-red-font-in-r-dt-datatable/55572811?noredirect=1#comment98834127_55572811), I can now style selected rows (intended for the user to select rows to be excluded from further analysis), but I have found out that sorting the datatable after executing the functionality to exclude rows (gray them out and add a different icon, keeps the icon in the correct row, but grays out the wrong rows.

here is the table after deselecting rows 2,3 and 4 before sorting: 
[image]

and after sort: (with the crosses at the right rows, but the graying out not.

[image]

```
   library(shiny)
      library(DT)

  mtcars <- as.data.table(mtcars[1:15, )
  ui <- fluidPage(
    # actionButton('SubmitRemoval', 'Exclude selected rows'),
    # actionButton('UndoRemoval', 'Include full data'),
    # br(),
    DTOutput('metadataTable')

  )

  server <- function(input, output,session) {

    values <- reactiveValues()

    rowCallbackMeta = function(rows){
      c(
        "function(row, data, num, index){",
        sprintf("  var rows = [%s];", paste0(rows-1, collapse = ",")),
        "  if(rows.indexOf(num) > -1){",
        "    for(var i=0; i<data.length; i++){",
        "      $('td:eq('+i+')', row)",
        "        .css({'color': 'rgb(211,211,211)', 'font-style': 'italic'});",
        "    }",
        "  }",
        "    $('td:eq(3)', row).html(data[3].toExponential(2));",
        "}"  
      )
    }
    output$metadataTable <-  DT::renderDataTable({

      rows <- values$RowsRemove

      # mtcars1 <- cbind(Selected ='<span style = "color:#31C769 ; font-size:18px"><i class="fa fa-check"></i></span>', mtcars)
      mtcars1 <- cbind(Selected ='<span style = "color:red ; font-size:18px"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok"></i></span>', mtcars)

      print(rows)
      # if(!is.null(rows)) { 
      mtcars1$Selected[rows] <- '<span style = "color:red ; font-size:18px"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></i></span>' 
      # }

      Table_opts <- list(
        dom = 'frtipB',
        searching = F,
        pageLength = 50,
        searchHighlight = TRUE,
        colReorder = TRUE,
        fixedHeader = TRUE,
        buttons = list('copy', 'csv',
                       list(
                         extend = "collection",
                         text = 'Deselect', 
                         action = DT::JS("function ( e, dt, node, config ) {
                                       Shiny.setInputValue('SubmitRemoval', true, {priority: 'event'});
                                     }")
                       ),
                       list(
                         extend = "collection",
                         text = 'Restore', 
                         action = DT::JS("function ( e, dt, node, config ) {
                                       Shiny.setInputValue('UndoRemoval', true, {priority: 'event'});
                                     }")
                       )
        ),
        paging    = TRUE,
        deferRender = TRUE,
        columnDefs = list(list(className = 'dt-right', targets = '_all')),
        rowCallback = JS(rowCallbackMeta(rows)),
        scrollX = T,
        scrollY = 440
      )
      DT::datatable(mtcars1, 
                    escape = FALSE, 
                    extensions = c('Buttons', 'ColReorder', 'FixedHeader', 'Scroller'),
                    selection = c('multiple'),
                    rownames = FALSE
                    ,
                    options = Table_opts
      )
    })


    observeEvent(values$RowsRemove, {
      print('seeing rows remove')
      values$Datafiles_meta_Selected  <-  values$Datafiles_meta_Selected[-c(values$RowsRemove),]
    })

    observeEvent(input[['SubmitRemoval']], { 
      if(is.null(values$RowsRemove)) { values$RowsRemove <- as.numeric()}
      values$RowsRemove <- unique(c(values$RowsRemove, input[["metadataTable_rows_selected"]]))
    })

    observeEvent(input[["UndoRemoval"]], { 
      values$RowsRemove <- NULL
      values$Datafiles_meta_Selected <- values$Datafiles_meta
    })

  }

  shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `num` you are using in your javascript to select rows to gray out is based on the row number on the current display so not impacted by sorting.

You could try replacing your `if` statement in your `rowCallbackMeta` function by:

```
if(data[0].search('remove') > -1)
```

This looks for "remove" in the first column of the data to exclude rows, and works because your glyphicon in the first column is updated to `<i class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></i>` when you exclude rows.