# Move javascript functionality of buttons to embedded buttons with DT datatable

Tags: javascript, r, shiny, dt

Related to a previous question, I am stuck on how to get javascript functionality running on embedded buttons in a datatable. 
I suspect it has to do with initiation of the javascript versus the rendering of the buttons, but so far I failed to figure out how to get the functionality work with the embedded buttons..

In the app below I gave the embedded buttons a different name, but in testing it without the regular actionbuttons in the app, and giving the embedded ones the same name, the javascript does not react it seems

[previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55550126/format-a-vector-of-rows-in-italic-and-red-font-in-r-dt-datatable)

```
library(shiny)
library(DT)

initComplete <- c(
  "function(settings) {",
  "  var table = settings.oInstance.api();", 
  "  var cross = '<span style=\"color:red; font-size:18px\"><i class=\"glyphicon glyphicon-remove\"></i></span>'",
  "  var checkmark = '<span style=\"color:red; font-size:18px\"><i class=\"glyphicon glyphicon-ok\"></i></span>'",
  "  $('#SubmitRemoval').on('click', function(){",
  "    table.$('tr.selected').addClass('x');",
  "    table.$('tr.selected')",
  "      .each(function(){$(this).find('td').eq(1).html(cross);});",
  "    var excludedRows = [];",
  "    table.$('tr').each(function(i, row){",
  "      if($(this).hasClass('x')){excludedRows.push(parseInt($(row).attr('id')));}",
  "    });",
  "    Shiny.setInputValue('excludedRows', excludedRows);",
  "  });",
  "  $('#UndoRemoval').on('click', function(){",
  "    table.$('tr').removeClass('x');",
  "    table.$('tr')",
  "      .each(function(i){$(this).find('td').eq(1).html(checkmark);});",
  "    Shiny.setInputValue('excludedRows', null);",
  "  });",
  "}"
)

callback <- "
var cross = '<span style=\"color:red; font-size:18px\"><i class=\"glyphicon glyphicon-remove\"></i></span>'
var xrows = [];
table.on('preDraw', function(e, settings) {
  var tbl = settings.oInstance.api();
  var nrows = tbl.rows().count();
  var rows = tbl.$('tr');
  var some = false; var r = 0;
  while(!some && r<nrows){
    if($(rows[r]).hasClass('x')){
      some = true
    }
    r++;
  }
  if(some){
    xrows = [];
    for(var i = 0; i < nrows; i++){
      if($(rows[i]).hasClass('x')){
        xrows.push(rows[i].getAttribute('id'));
      }
    }
  }
}).on('draw.dt', function(){
  for(var i=0; i<xrows.length; i++){
    var row = $('#' + xrows[i]);
    row.addClass('x').find('td').eq(1).html(cross);
  }
  xrows = [];
});
"

ui <- fluidPage(
  tags$head(
    tags$style(HTML(
      ".x { background-color: rgb(211,211,211) !important; font-style: italic}
       table.dataTable tr.selected.x td { background-color: rgb(211,211,211) !important;}"
    ))
  ),
  actionButton('SubmitRemoval', 'Exclude selected rows'),
  actionButton('UndoRemoval', 'Include full data'),
  br(),
  DTOutput('mytable')

)

server <- function(input, output,session) {

  dat <- cbind(Selected = '<span style="color:red; font-size:18px"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok"></i></span>', 
               mtcars[1:6,], id = 1:6)

  output[["mytable"]] <- renderDT({
    datatable(dat, 
              escape = -2, 
              callback = JS(callback),
              extensions = c('Buttons', 'Scroller'),

              options = list(
                initComplete = JS(initComplete),
                rowId = JS(sprintf("function(data){return data[%d];}", ncol(dat))), 
                columnDefs = list(
                  list(visible = FALSE, targets = ncol(dat)),
                  list(className = "dt-center", targets = "_all")
                ), 
                dom = 'frtipB',

                buttons = list('copy', 'csv',
                               list(
                                 extend = "collection",
                                 text = 'Deselect', 
                                 action = DT::JS("function ( e, dt, node, config ) {
                                       Shiny.setInputValue('SubmitRemovalEmb', true, {priority: 'event'});
                                     }")
                               ),
                               list(
                                 extend = "collection",
                                 text = 'Restore', 
                                 action = DT::JS("function ( e, dt, node, config ) {
                                       Shiny.setInputValue('UndoRemovalEmb', true, {priority: 'event'});
                                     }")
                               )
                )

              )
    )
  })

  proxy <- dataTableProxy("mytable")

  observeEvent(input[["UndoRemoval"]], { 
    proxy %>% selectRows(NULL)
  })

}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

**UPDATE2**
working answer with modifications and corrections included. looking at last finishing touches based on last comment

```
library(shiny)
library(DT)


callback <- "
var cross = '<span style=\"color:red; font-size:18px\"><i class=\"glyphicon glyphicon-remove\"></i></span>'
var xrows = [];
table.on('preDraw', function(e, settings) {
  var tbl = settings.oInstance.api();
  var nrows = tbl.rows().count();
  var rows = tbl.$('tr');
  var some = false; var r = 0;
  while(!some && r<nrows){
    if($(rows[r]).hasClass('x')){
      some = true
    }
    r++;
  }
  if(some){
    xrows = [];
    for(var i = 0; i < nrows; i++){
      if($(rows[i]).hasClass('x')){
        xrows.push(rows[i].getAttribute('id'));
      }
    }
  }
}).on('draw.dt', function(){
  for(var i=0; i<xrows.length; i++){
    var row = $('#' + xrows[i]);
    row.addClass('x').find('td').eq(1).html(cross);
  }
  xrows = [];
});
"

ui <- fluidPage(
  tags$head(
    tags$style(HTML(
      ".x { font-style: italic}"
    ))
  ),

  br(),
  DTOutput('mytable')

)

server <- function(input, output,session) {

  dat <- cbind(Selected = '<span style="color:red; font-size:18px"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok"></i></span>', 
               mtcars[1:6,], id = 1:6)

  output[["mytable"]] <- renderDT({
    datatable(dat, 
              escape = -2, 
              callback = JS(callback),
              extensions = c('Buttons', 'Scroller'),
              options = list(
                rowId = JS(sprintf("function(data){return data[%d];}", ncol(dat))), 
                columnDefs = list(
                  list(visible = FALSE, targets = ncol(dat)),
                  list(className = "dt-center", targets = "_all")
                ), 
                dom = 'B',
                buttons = list('copy', 'csv',
                               list(
                                 extend = "collection",
                                 text = 'Deselect', 
                                 action = DT::JS(
                                   c(
                                     "function ( e, table, node, config ) {",
                                     "  var cross = '<span style=\"color:red; font-size:18px\"><i class=\"glyphicon glyphicon-remove\"></i></span>'",
                                     "  table.$('tr.selected').addClass('x');",
                                     "  table.$('tr.selected')",
                                     "    .each(function(){$(this).find('td').eq(1).html(cross);}).removeClass('selected');",
                                     "    var excludedRows = [];",
                                     "    table.$('tr').each(function(i, row){",
                                     "      if($(this).hasClass('x')){excludedRows.push(parseInt($(row).attr('id')));}",
                                     "    });",
                                     "    Shiny.setInputValue('excludedRows', excludedRows);",
                                     "}"
                                   )
                                 )   
                               ),
                               list(
                                 extend = "collection",
                                 text = 'Restore', 
                                 action = DT::JS(
                                   c(
                                     "function ( e, table, node, config ) {",
                                     "  var checkmark = '<span style=\"color:red; font-size:18px\"><i class=\"glyphicon glyphicon-ok\"></i></span>'",
                                     "    table.$('tr')",
                                     "      .each(function(i){$(this).find('td').eq(1).html(checkmark);});",
                                     "    table.$('tr').removeClass('x').removeClass('selected');",
                                     "    Shiny.setInputValue('excludedRows', null);",
                                     " }"
                                   )
                                 )
                               )

                )
              )
    )
  })

  proxy <- dataTableProxy("mytable")



  observeEvent(input[['excludedRows']], { 
    print(input[['excludedRows']])}, ignoreInit =  T)


}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

**ps to comment about select:**
i removed the css entirely, except for the italic part. I mean that after clicking deselect or restore, i would like to unselect the clicked rows, shown in this image in blue (the color they get when you click them)

**UPDATE question**

I'm trying to change the `Selected`  column to hold `T` and `F`values and I think I managed to get the `remove` and `restore codes working with that, but I am not sure how to get the new render function working. What I have so far is this:

```
render <- c(
  'function(data, type, row, meta){',
  '  if(type === "display"){',
  '    return "<span style=\\\"color:red; font-size:18px\\\"><i class=\\\"glyphicon glyphicon-remove\\\"></i></span>";',
  '  } else {',
  '    return "<span style=\\\"color:red; font-size:18px\\\"><i class=\\\"glyphicon glyphicon-ok\\\"></i></span>";',
  '  }',
  '}'
)
```

The problem is that I don't know what to change the obviously incorrect IF statement for:  `'  if(type === "display"){',`
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The argument `dt` of the button action function (`function(e,dt,node,config)`) is the DataTables instance API for the host DataTable: https://datatables.net/reference/option/buttons.buttons.action

In the `initComplete` function `function(settings)`, this object is `settings.oInstance.api()`, which is named `table` in the JS code (`var table = settings.oInstance.api();`).

So replace `function(e,dt,node,config)` with `function(e,table,node,config)`, and move the JS code to the body of the button action function:

```
action = DT::JS(
  c(
    "function ( e, table, node, config ) {",
    "  var cross = '<span style=\"color:red; font-size:18px\"><i class=\"glyphicon glyphicon-remove\"></i></span>'",
    "  table.$('tr.selected').addClass('x');",
    "  table.$('tr.selected')",
    "    .each(function(){$(this).find('td').eq(1).html(cross);});",
    "}"
  )
)
```

## EDIT

Here is the full code for the updated solution:

```
library(shiny)
library(DT)

removal <- c(
  "function(e, table, node, config) {",
  "  table.$('tr.selected').addClass('x').each(function(){",
  "    var td = $(this).find('td').eq(1)[0];", 
  "    var cell = table.cell(td);", 
  "    cell.data('remove');",
  "  });",
  "  table.rows().deselect();",
  "  var excludedRows = [];",
  "  table.$('tr').each(function(i, row){",
  "    if($(this).hasClass('x')){excludedRows.push(parseInt($(row).attr('id')));}",
  "  });",
  "  Shiny.setInputValue('excludedRows', excludedRows);",
  "}"
)

restore <- c(
  "function(e, table, node, config) {",
  "  table.$('tr').removeClass('x').each(function(){",
  "    var td = $(this).find('td').eq(1)[0];", 
  "    var cell = table.cell(td);", 
  "    cell.data('ok');",
  "  });",
  "  Shiny.setInputValue('excludedRows', null);",
  "}"
)

render <- c(
  'function(data, type, row, meta){',
  '  if(type === "display"){',
  '    return "<span style=\\\"color:red; font-size:18px\\\"><i class=\\\"glyphicon glyphicon-" + data + "\\\"></i></span>";',
  '  } else {',
  '    return data;',
  '  }',
  '}'
)

ui <- fluidPage(
  tags$head(
    tags$style(HTML(
      ".x { color: rgb(211,211,211); font-style: italic; }"
    ))
  ),
  fluidRow(
    column(
      6, 
      tags$label("Excluded rows"),
      verbatimTextOutput("excludedRows")
    ),
    column(
      6, 
      tags$label("Included rows"),
      verbatimTextOutput("includedRows")
    )
  ),
  br(),
  DTOutput('mytable')
)

server <- function(input, output,session) {

  dat <- cbind(Selected = "ok", mtcars[1:6,], id = 1:6)

  output[["mytable"]] <- renderDT({
    datatable(dat, 
              extensions = c("Select", "Buttons"),
              options = list(
                rowId = JS(sprintf("function(data){return data[%d];}", ncol(dat))), 
                columnDefs = list(
                  list(visible = FALSE, targets = ncol(dat)),
                  list(className = "dt-center", targets = "_all"),
                  list(targets = 1, render = JS(render)) 
                ),
                dom = "B",
                buttons = list("copy", "csv",
                               list(
                                 extend = "collection",
                                 text = 'Deselect', 
                                 action = JS(removal)
                               ),
                               list(
                                 extend = "collection",
                                 text = 'Restore', 
                                 action = JS(restore)
                               )
                )
              )
    )
  }, server = FALSE)

    output$excludedRows <- renderPrint({
      input[["excludedRows"]]
    })

    output$includedRows <- renderPrint({
      setdiff(1:nrow(dat), input[["excludedRows"]])
    })

}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

[image]

---

## "Deselect" from shiny server: example

```
library(shiny)
library(DT)
library(shinyjs)

js <- paste(
  "var table = $('#mytable').find('table').DataTable();",
  "var rowsindices = [%s];",
  "for(var i=0; i<rowsindices.length; ++i){",
  "  var idx = rowsindices[i];",
  "  table.cell(idx, 1).data('remove');",
  "  table.row(idx).select();",
  "}",
  "$('.dt-button.buttons-collection').eq(0).click();", 
  sep = "\n"
)

removal <- c(
  "function(e, table, node, config) {",
  "  table.$('tr.selected').addClass('x').each(function(){",
  "    var td = $(this).find('td').eq(1)[0];", 
  "    var cell = table.cell(td);", 
  "    cell.data('remove');",
  "  });",
  "  table.rows().deselect();",
  "  var excludedRows = [];",
  "  table.$('tr').each(function(i, row){",
  "    if($(this).hasClass('x')){excludedRows.push(parseInt($(row).attr('id')));}",
  "  });",
  "    Shiny.setInputValue('excludedRows', excludedRows);",
  "}"
)

restore <- c(
  "function(e, table, node, config) {",
  "  table.$('tr').removeClass('x').each(function(){",
  "    var td = $(this).find('td').eq(1)[0];", 
  "    var cell = table.cell(td);", 
  "    cell.data('ok');",
  "  });",
  "  Shiny.setInputValue('excludedRows', null);",
  "}"
)

render <- c(
  'function(data, type, row, meta){',
  '  if(type === "display"){',
  '    return "<span style=\\\"color:red; font-size:18px\\\"><i class=\\\"glyphicon glyphicon-" + data + "\\\"></i></span>";',
  '  } else {',
  '    return data;',
  '  }',
  '}'
)

ui <- fluidPage(
  useShinyjs(),
  tags$head(
    tags$style(HTML(
      ".x { color: rgb(211,211,211); font-style: italic; }"
    ))
  ),
  fluidRow(
    column(
      6, 
      tags$label("Excluded rows"),
      verbatimTextOutput("excludedRows")
    ),
    column(
      6, 
      tags$label("Included rows"),
      verbatimTextOutput("includedRows")
    )
  ),
  br(), 
  actionButton("go", "Deselect rows 1, 2, 3"),
  br(),
  DTOutput('mytable')
)

server <- function(input, output,session) {

  dat <- cbind(Selected = "ok", mtcars[1:6,], id = 1:6)

  output[["mytable"]] <- renderDT({
    datatable(dat, 
              extensions = c("Select", "Buttons"),
              options = list(
                rowId = JS(sprintf("function(data){return data[%d];}", ncol(dat))), 
                columnDefs = list(
                  list(visible = FALSE, targets = ncol(dat)),
                  list(className = "dt-center", targets = "_all"),
                  list(targets = 1, render = JS(render)) 
                ),
                dom = "B",
                buttons = list("copy", "csv",
                               list(
                                 extend = "collection",
                                 text = 'Deselect', 
                                 action = JS(removal)
                               ),
                               list(
                                 extend = "collection",
                                 text = 'Restore', 
                                 action = JS(restore)
                               )
                )
              )
    )
  }, server = FALSE)

  output$excludedRows <- renderPrint({
    input[["excludedRows"]]
  })

  output$includedRows <- renderPrint({
    setdiff(1:nrow(dat), input[["excludedRows"]])
  })

  observeEvent(input[["go"]], {
    rows <- c(1,2,3) - 1
    runjs(sprintf(js, paste0(rows, collapse=",")))
  })

}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: I tried, got some of it working, but stuck again (see update). My current progress also removes all deselects when you sort a column

Comment: @Mark Several problems... 1) In `callback`, you don't have to replace `table` with `dt`. 2) The argument `callback = JS(callback)` is missing in `datatable`. 3) Remove the option `initComplete`, there's no `initComplete` anymore. 4) There's a missing parenthesis in your code. 5) In the `Restore` button, you have not defined `checkmark`.

Comment: Ok, I think I figured out most of the corrections you mentioned now, except it goes wrong with sorting now....updated code in my question update

Comment: ps im guessing the error with sorting is in my callback, but I can't make sense of how to ammend it

Comment: @Mark You have not copied the good `callback` code from the previous question. There's a `var cross` in the last one.

Comment: Ah I see yes. I see three final minor issues to make it work flawless. 
1) Sorting of 'selected' doesn't work properly (I can get xxvvv but reverse order no), i guess because the other rows have no class?
2) the two buttons might also remove the current selection (blue rows), i removed the color change of removed rows 
3) How could we get the rows to keep out instead of the removed rows... (!'x') perhaps?

Comment: @Mark For 1) I don't know. I'll take a look one day. I don't understand 2). For 3) it's easier to get them in R from the excluded rows.

Comment: for one, can we add a class 'y' to all rows that don't have class 'x' when pressing deselect (not to apply to all unselected rows as that would turn previous deselected rows into class y while they should stay class x when pressing deselect button), and the restore button could add class 'y' to all rows

Comment: trying to add something like this:                                      "    table.$('tr').each(function(i, row){",
                                     "            if(!$(this).hasClass('x')).addClass('y');}", but that resulted in a blank page

Comment: for two I meant that after clicking deselect or restore, the selected rows stay selected (hightlighted bright blue), I would like to clear the selection. I tried adding various approaches along the lines of .rows().deselect() or  "   table.$('tr').rows().deselect();", but no success.

Comment: For 2) what you say is not true. This is the role of the CSS `table.dataTable tr.selected.x td { background-color: rgb(211,211,211) !important;}`. Have you changed something ? Maybe the class name (`x`) ? If you have changed it, then change it also here: `tr.selected.x`.

Comment: PS: in fact with this CSS the row is still selected, but its background color is overridden.

Comment: I have removed the entire color aspect from the css, only left the italic font part. I'm talking about the mouse click blue. see ps update and image above

Comment: @Mark Ah ok you don't want to set a background color. Then add this CSS: `table.dataTable tr.selected.x td { background-color: #ffffff !important;}`.

Comment: yeah I know that for no background at all, but this is not related to background but to highlight of selection

Comment: @Mark The highlighting is nothing but a background color. I would try to replace `.each(function(){$(this).find('td').eq(1).html(cross);});` with `.each(function(){$(this).find('td').eq(1).html(cross);}).removeClass('selected');`.

Comment: ah cool, that works. Also added remove to the other button (see updated code above). But, strangely enough the selection reappears when sorting the table (any column)....

Comment: @SL, I'm trying to adjust your last answer to work with the "Selected" column containing T and F values (easier for the rest of my app that uses the same dataframe, but the last bit is eluding me, i.e. how to alter the render function. 
i'm adding the attempt to the bottom of my question in a moment

Comment: @Mark In my render function, just after `if(type === "display"){`, do `var x = data == true ? 'ok' : 'remove';`. Then in the line after, replace `+ data +` with `+ x +`.

Comment: that worked nicely. One new puzzle piece... I'm using the same dataframe for both this table, and a plot where the user can also select deselect points. The plot currently directly alters the "Selected" column values from T to F and vice versa, but the table doesn't.  Using the `excludedRows` value to change `dataframe$Selected` as in the code of the answer, does however of course trigger a re-rendering of the table, and plot. .... but without Italic of course. 
Should we add a way to add 'italic' to the render function somehow or do you have a better idea how to link the 2 objects?

Comment: @Mark The `render` function only alters the cells in one column. I'm not sure to get your problem. You "manually" modify `dataframe$Selected` and you want the italic ?

Comment: Yes manual manipulation would pretty much come down to the same thing

Comment: @Mark see my update ("Deselect from shiny server"). You put the indices of the rows you want to exclude in a vector `x`, and then you run `runjs(sprintf(js, paste0(x-1, collapse=",")))`. The JS code changes the cells contents to 'remove', selects the rows, and triggers the click on the 'Deselect' button.

Comment: Great! thanks for that suggestion @SL. Right now I'm trying to understand why the render function ONLY works if "Selected" is column 1 in the dataframe. (it failed as my export from the main app i'm testing with puts it as last column, but I can reorder it of course), but would rather understand the render function better. what do the 4 input arguments refer to ? I'm guessing "display" refers to DT hidden or show functionality, data is the dataframe in the table, row is perform the function over each row, but what does "meta" refer to, and why does it target row one in the solution exactly?

Comment: @Mark It targets column 1 because of the option `list(targets = 1, render = JS(render))`. The `data` argument refers to the data in the cell, in this example `ok` or `remove`. The `type` argument can take several values, like `display` and `sort`. If `display`, what you return in the `render` function is displayed in the cell; this allows to render something different to `data` without altering the data. If `sort`, the value you return in the `render` function is the value that is used for sorting the column. See [here](https://datatables.net/reference/option/columns.render) for more info.

Comment: yes I just found out about the list(targets = ?, render = JS(render)) part, and also how to alter which column to find the id in, i.e. rowId = JS(sprintf("function(data){return data[%d];}", ?)), I will recode it for my app to figure out which column contains the needed info based on column name searching with `which(names(df) == 'id')`

Comment: Stephane, I have finally build all the table and regression plots into my main program, but now I discovered an unwanted side effect. Due to `}, server = FALSE)` in the table, I found out that it doesn't update when the dataframe used for the table changes (i.e. the user selects another set of files in the previous step), i.e. in my case 'values$dat' changes completely. Do you have any idea how that could be solved?

Comment: @Mark Are you using a proxy ? That does not work with `server = FALSE`.

Comment: I found the cause.... No i'm not using proxy in my code for the table, basically can reproduce it in your answer here as well, stick the table inside a dropdownButton, and I had  outputOptions(output, "mytable", suspendWhenHidden=FALSE) in my code, which appears to be the reason why it did'nt update. It does update if I move the table to the front page, hence my hunch that it was something with the hidden aspect.