# JavaScript function for DT formatting (R shiny)

Tags: javascript, r, shiny, dt

I need to design the R Shiny data table, using Java Script like that (like stairs on the DT bottom, which shows the prediction values - *italic* and gray).

[image]

I'm trying to use this function ([From this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55550126/format-a-vector-of-rows-in-italic-and-red-font-in-r-dt-datatable)), but all my table is *italic* starting from 3rd column. How can I fix it? (suppose, that my for loop is incorrect)

```
  rowCallback <- function(rows){
c(
  "function(row, data, num){",
  sprintf("  var rows = [%s];", paste0(rows-1, collapse = ",")),
  "  for(let j=data.length; j >= 3; j--){",
  "    for(let i=j; i<data.length; i++){",
  "      $('td:eq('+i+')', row)",
  "        .css({'background-color': 'rgb(211,211,211)', 'font-style': 'italic', 'font-color': 'rgb(230,230,230)'});",
  "    }",
  "  }",
  "}"  
)
```

}

Answer (score 1):

Not tested, I would try:

```r
rowCallback <- c(
  "function(row, data, num, index){",
  "  var ncols = data.length;",
  "  for(let j=ncols; j > ncols-index; j--){",
  "    $('td:eq('+j+')', row)",
  "      .css({'background-color': 'rgb(211,211,211)', 'font-style': 'italic', 'font-color': 'rgb(230,230,230)'});",
  "  }",
  "}"  
)
```

**Notes:**

- You don't need a R function, because the `rows` argument is not used.
- `$('td:eq('+j+')', row)` selects the j-th element of the current row, so you don't have to loop over rows.