# How to add a column of radio buttons for deleting rows?

Tags: r, shiny, radio-button, dt

In this example, I'm removing rows of the `datatable` using `checkboxGroupInput`, but I'd prefer to have a column of radio buttons in the table itself to select which rows to remove. I've tried reading the documentation and examples that others have posted, but I can't decipher any of it. How can I solve this?

```r
library(shiny)
library(DT)

mtcars[["cars"]] <- row.names(mtcars)
example_mtcars <- head(mtcars, n = 5)
ui <- fluidPage(
  checkboxGroupInput("mtcars_update", "Select Cars to Remove", choices = example_mtcars$cars),
  shiny::dataTableOutput("mtcars_dt")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  output$mtcars_dt <- shiny::renderDataTable({
    if (length(input$mtcars_update) == 0) {
      example_mtcars
    } else {
      example_mtcars |>
        dplyr::filter(cars != input$mtcars_update)
    }
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

<sup>Created on 2024-03-16 with [reprex v2.1.0](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: It's strange to use radio buttons. A radio button is either selected or not selected. I would rather use an icon, e.g. a red cross.

Comment: hey, i'm open to all suggestions if you're willing to share something. i think what i eventually want to do is be able to sample the dataset, and have one column marking rows that won't be included in the sample, and another column marking rows that must be included in the sample. all the remaining columns would be optional in the sample.

Comment: something like [that](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56405204/1100107)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

```
library(shiny)
library(DT)

mtcars[["cars"]] <- row.names(mtcars)
example_mtcars <- head(mtcars, n = 5) |>
    dplyr::mutate(Remove = sprintf(
        paste0('<input type="radio" id = "radioB', dplyr::row_number(), '"/>')
    ),
    .before = mpg)

js <- c(
    "table.rows().every(function(i, tab, row) {",
    "    var $this = $(this.node());",
    "    $this.attr('id', this.data()[0]);",
    "    $this.addClass('shiny-input-radiogroup');",
    "});",
    "Shiny.unbindAll(table.table().node());",
    "Shiny.bindAll(table.table().node());",
    "$('[id^=radioB]').on('click', function(){",
    "  Shiny.setInputValue('dtable_radioButtonClicked:DT.cellInfo', null);",
    "  var i = $(this).closest('tr').index() + 1;",
    "  var info = [{row: i}];",
    "  Shiny.setInputValue('dtable_radioButtonClicked:DT.cellInfo', info);",
    "})"
)

ui <- fluidPage(
    DT::dataTableOutput("mtcars_dt")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
    my_mtcars <- reactiveValues(df = example_mtcars)
    
    output$mtcars_dt <- DT::renderDataTable(
        my_mtcars$df,
        callback = JS(js),
        selection = 'none',
        escape = FALSE,
        server = FALSE
    )
    
    observeEvent(input[["dtable_radioButtonClicked"]], {
        rowToDelete <- input[["dtable_radioButtonClicked"]]$row
        my_mtcars$df <- my_mtcars$df[-rowToDelete]
    }, ignoreNULL = TRUE)
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```